# Using too many .and in my test how make it better. [Cypress]

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, ui-automation

I have written the below script and I feel I am using too many `.and` is there a more convenient way to write this?

```
 cy.get('[data-cy="resumeSelectHiringManagerRowGroupLink"]')
    .should('contain', '3')  
    .and ('contain', 'Resumes') 
    .and ('contain', 'awaiting next status change since')
    .and ('contain', '7+ days')
    .and ('contain', 'under')
    .and ('contain', 'Resume Select - Hiring Manager')
```

Comment: Checking your element contains so much different text doesn't seem very strong. If you need to verify one element contains all that text, you can either use a regex to match all that or maybe drill down into each individual element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten you code by doing like this:

```js
const texts = [
  '3',
  'Resumes',
  'awaiting next status change since',
  '7+ days',
  'under',
  'Resume Select - Hiring Manager',
]
texts.forEach((text) => {
  cy.get('[data-cy="resumeSelectHiringManagerRowGroupLink"]').should(
    'contain',
    text
  )
})
```